Bootstrap dropdown autoClose doesn't work through javascript
I use this code for toggle bootstrap 5 dropdown but autoClose configuration didn't affect.
const dropdown = new bootstrap.Dropdown(document.querySelector('.dropdown-menu'), {
   autoClose: true
})
dropdown.toggle()

 <div>
    <div class="dropdown-menu p-4">
      ...
    </div>
 </div>


I think you're initializing the Dropdown on the wrong element. In Bootstrap 5, the dropdown should be initialized on the button or toggle element, because is the element responsible for controlling the dropdown's behavior.
Assumming the rest of the dropdown is something like this:
<div class="dropdown-menu p-4">
    <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
        Dropdown button
    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>

Try this:
const dropdown = new bootstrap.Dropdown(document.querySelector('.dropdown-toggle'), {
   autoClose: true
});
dropdown.toggle();


I did this too but still not working.
